# How to mapping @Field in xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, mapping

Can someone help me how to map this code in xml (Hibernate)

```
@Column(name = "title", nullable= false, length = 128)
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String title;

@Column(name = "description", nullable= false, length = 256)
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String description;

@Column(name = "author", nullable= false, length = 64)
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String author;
```

Its easy to map @Column, but i dont know how to map @Field in xml file.

Ref : [Integrating Full Text Search to Spring MVC with Hibernate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830529/Integrating-Full-Text-Search-to-Spring-MVC-with-Hi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search annotations care currently not supported via XML, see [the hibernate documentation](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/):

> Hibernate Search has its own set of annotations (@Indexed, @DocumentId, @Field,…​) for which there exists so far no XML based alternative; if annotations aren’t suited for your project, a better option is the Programmatic Mapping API.